# How to create a unmanaged struct in powershell containing plain arrays?

Tags: arrays, .net, powershell, struct

I need to assemble a blob in a Powershell script that shows the following layout:

```
_Pragma("pack(1)")
struct MyConfig {
    uint16_t level;
    uint16_t thresholds[16];
    // ... the struct contains lots of POD members, but no pointers
}

struct MyConfig config = {
    .level = 1,
    .thresholds = {
        1, 2, 3, 4, ...
    }
};
```

The resulting `config` struct instance shall be dumped to a file.

I am able to solve the first part for integral types, but I am not able to access array members:

```
$typeCode = @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
[Serializable]
public struct MyConfig
{
    public Int16 level;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)] public Int32[] thresholds;
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $typeCode

$config = New-Object MyConfig
$config.level = 1 # works
$config.thresholds[0] = 1 # Cannot index into a null array.
```

I have not looked at serializing the struct, yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[MarshalAs()]` attribute you've decorated the `thresholds` member with is just *metadata* for marshalling data between unmanaged and managed memory - it doesn't actually *do* anything in the context of managed code.

To be able to assign to the array slots, you need to initialize `thresholds` with an actual array instance:

```
$config.thresholds = [int[]]::new(16)
$config.thresholds[0] = 1
```

You can also use PowerShell's cast-based object initializer syntax to initialize both members at once:

```
$config = [MyConfig]@{
    level = 1
    thresholds = [int[]]::new(16)
}
$config.thresholds[0] = 1
```

---

To serialize the struct to a byte array, use the same approach as if you were to marshal it for use with an unmanaged library, then write the resulting byte stream to disk instead:

```
using namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices

# Calculate in-memory size of struct = length of resulting byte stream
$streamLength = [Marshal]::SizeOf($config)
$structBytes  = [byte[]]::new($streamLength)
$structCopied = $false

# Allocate unmanaged memory, copy struct memory to it, then copy back to managed array
try {
    $memPtr = [IntPtr]::Zero
    $memPtr = [Marshal]::AllocHGlobal($streamLength)
    [Marshal]::StructureToPtr($config, $memPtr, $true)
    [Marshal]::Copy($memPtr, $structBytes, 0, $streamLength)
    $structCopied = $true
}
finally {
    if($memPtr -ne [IntPtr]::Zero){
        [Marshal]::FreeHGlobal($memPtr)
    }
}

# Write resulting byte stream to file
if($structCopied){
    try {
        $outFile = New-Item output.bin
        $outHandle = $outFile.OpenWrite()
        $outHandle.Write($structBytes, 0, $streamLength)
    }
    finally {
        if($outHandle -is [IDisposable]){
            $outHandle.Dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

This produces a byte stream of length 66, which fits what you'd expect given the struct layout:

- 2 bytes for `level`
- 64 (16 * 4) bytes for `thresholds`

Comment: Thanks. Do you also have a suggestion how to serialize the resulting object into a byte array / file?

Comment: @RichardW Depends on your requirements - what's the purpose of serializing to disk?

Comment: The generated blob goes eventually into a firmware implemented in C and is read by casting it to a type following the same layout as MyConfig above. For reasons I cannot simply generate code and compile the struct with the firmware and I can also not use a proper serialization format like flatbuffers. I am aware that this is risky and have prepared for that.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73623544/45375) with background information and more convenient solutions:

**C# `struct`s (.NET value types) do not support members that are *embedded* arrays of fixed length**:

It is only ever a *reference* (pointer) to an array (of unspecified size) that is stored in the `struct` itself, and that reference is `null` when an instance of the `struct` is created by default.

An alternative to allocating and assigning a fixed-size array to your `.thresholds` field *after* construction of an instance is to **declare a public *constructor* that performs the array initialization**.

In **C# 10+ / PowerShell (Core) 7.2.+**, you can do this as follows:

```bash
$typeCode = @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
[Serializable]
public struct MyConfig
{
    // Explicit default (parameterless) constructor that initializes the fields.
    // Note: ALL fields must be initialized.
    public MyConfig() { level = 0; thresholds = new Int32[16]; }
    public Int16 level;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)] public Int32[] thresholds;
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $typeCode

# Construct an instance.
[MyConfig]::new()
```

The above prints the following to the display; the `{0, 0, 0, 0…}` part implies that the array was allocated:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0…}
```

In **C# 9- / Windows PowerShell** and earlier PowerShell (Core) versions), *parameterless* constructors aren't supported, so a workaround is needed:

Declare a constructor with a *dummy parameter* that has a *default* value:

```bash
$typeCode = @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
[Serializable]
public struct MyConfig
{
    // Note the `int unused = 0` dummy parameter.
    public MyConfig(int unused = 0) { level = 0; thresholds = new Int32[16]; }
    public Int16 level;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)] public Int32[] thresholds;
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $typeCode

# Construct an instance.
# Do NOT use New-Object MyConfig (see below).
[MyConfig]::new()
```

**Caveats**:

- The constructor with the optional parameter is only called if you use `[MyConfig]::new()` to construct an instance; `New-Object MyConfig` does *not* do that, even though you'd expect the two command forms to be equivalent. The problem has been reported in [GitHub issue #18049](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18049)
- In C# code, using `default(MyConfig)` does *not* call either constructor, because the purpose of `default()` is simply to zero out the `struct`s members.